# Simple haskell code can't compile

Tags: haskell

I start learning Haskell, and just tried a simple code, and it shows me some errors when I run

```hs
doubleMe :: Int -> Int
doubleMe x = x + x

main = do
    doubleMe 2
```

> ghc -c first.hs

The errors are:

> $ ghc -c first.hs
>
> first.hs:4:1:
>       Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type`Int'
>       In the expression: main
>       When checking the type of the function `main'

While I use GCHi to debug, there were no issues to load `doubleMe` function first, and call it later. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest using ghci (the interactive environment) so you don't have to compile your code for simple hand testing. You could have just typed `:l first.hs` to load your definitions and then `doubleMe 2` without the crufty edit-main-every-time-I-want-to-check-something faf. (See answers for advice on how to write `main`.)

Comment: Wow... thanks a lot for all the people answering my questions so quickly. I'm very impressed by the friendly attitude to newbies in the Haskell community. Everybody's comments could have been accepted as the answer, but since there can only be one answer be accepted, I choose @tanmaig's, since he has the most thorough explanation. Thank you all again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every function in Haskell returns a value of a certain type.

In this case, the `doubleMe` function returns a value of the `Int` type. When you load a file from the ghci interpreter, it loads all the functions from the file and makes them available to you.

The `main` function is a slightly special function, much like in other languages. It defines the entry point of a Haskell program. However, since it is just another Haskell function it too must return a value of a particular type. The `main` function is constrained to return a value of the `IO` type, most commonly `IO ()`.

`IO` itself is quite special too, belonging to a class of types called monads. You can read up on the `IO` monad [here.](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html)

Let us now return to your code:

```
main = do
    doubleMe 2
```

Ignore the `do` syntax for a moment. You're basically telling the compiler that the `main` function returns `doubleMe 2` which is of type `Int`. This won't fly. `main` *has* to return a value of `IO` type. In which case, you can use the `return` function to convert an `Int` value into an `IO Int` value. (`return` functions are functions that all monadic types must have. Very simply put, it converts a value of any type, into a monadic value.)

So this becomes:

```
main = do
    return (doubleMe 2)
```

This is perfectly valid code, and will compile. However, once you run the program, you'll notice that it doesn't do anything. That's because the program *returns* the value 4. 
In fact, you can write it without the do, and it becomes:

```
main = return (doubleMe 2)
```

This will work too.

Let us assume however, that you want to print out the value. This is where `IO` really comes in. Printing to a screen is an `IO` action.

```
main = do
          print (doubleMe 2)
          return (doubleMe 2)
```

A `do`  expression allows you to *chain* a set of `IO` actions. So your program will still return the value `4` but it will first evaluate the expression `print (doubleMe 2)`. As expected, that actually results in printing the value `doubleMe 2`. 
Examine the `print` function in ghci.

```
> :t print
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

The print function works on a value of any type that can be *shown* and it results in an `IO` action (printing to the screen) but returns nothing `()`.

All of these examples work, and will hopefully make things a little clear. (Look at the type signatures for `main`).

```
-- main :: IO Int
main = return (doubleMe 2)

-- main :: IO Int
main = do 
          print (doubleMe 2)
          return (doubleMe 2)

-- main :: IO ()
main = do
          print (doubleMe 2)
          return ()

-- main :: IO ()
main = do
          print (doubleMe 2)

-- main :: IO ()
main = print (doubleMe 2)

-- main :: IO ()
main = do
         print "Hello"
         print (doubleMe 2)
         return ()

-- main :: IO String
main = do
         print "Hello"
         print (doubleMe 2)
         return "Hello"
```

Answer (score 6):

`main` must be a value of type `IO a`, and `doubleMe 2` has type `Int`.  You probably wanted to `print` the value:

```
main = print (doubleMe 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because anything using do notation must return a monad. GHCI does some things to make it more useful but it doesn't exactly work like code compiled by GHC.

`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`

`print` takes a value that is an instance of `Show` and returns an empty `IO` action. This is most likely what you want to do.

`main = print (doubleMe 2)`

Should work as probably what you want to do. You don't have the type of the `main` function defined but in haskell in has to have the type `main :: IO ()`. Looking at the type of `doubleMe` you can probably see why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't say things like "return a monad". It's sloppy wording that encourages sloppy thinking. Being a monad is a predicate on a type constructor. Functions return values, not types. Keeping the type and value level separate is vital for understanding Haskell, and we should be especially careful when teaching beginners.  Say something like "`main` must be an `IO` value, and your expression isn't," or something. Communicating clearly and precisely really is important.

Comment: Not to mention, it's also flat-out false that `do` blocks must result in a value of a monadic type. `do ()` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` function takes nothing and returns an integer. You probably want

```hs
doubleMe :: Int -> Int
doubleMe x = x + x

main = do
    print $ doubleMe 2
```

which instead outputs 4 to STDOUT.

Congratulations, you have run into [Monads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29). `main` is an IO monad and must act as such. IO monads do not return `Int`s. Instead an IO Monad is an IO action, returned by `print` and executed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things happening behind the scenes that make it hard to understand this error message. Here's the reasoning:

1. Your file doesn't have a module name, so ghc assumes that you are defining module `Main`.
2. The name `main` in module `Main` has to have type `IO something`.
3. But the `main` you wrote has type `Int`.
4. `IO something` is not the same as `Int`, no matter what we choose for the `something`.

GHC only reports the last step.

If you want to print the `Int`, you can use `print` to construct an IO action:

```
main = do
  print (doubleMe 2)
```

This problem doesn't show up in ghci, because there, you can enter expressions of whatever type you want. If the type is `IO something`, ghci will execute the IO action for you. (Example: `readFile "foo.txt"`). If the type is not `IO something`, ghci will add a call to `print` and then execute that IO action (Example: `['a' .. 'z']`).

In a source file, you have to add the call to `print` yourself if you want it or need it.