# Understanding I/O monad and the use of "do" notation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, do-notation

I am still struggling with Haskell and now I have encountered a problem with wrapping my mind around the Input/Output monad [from this example](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#hello-world):

```
main = do   
line <- getLine  
if null line  
    then return ()  
    else do  
        putStrLn $ reverseWords line  
        main  
  
reverseWords :: String -> String  
reverseWords = unwords . map reverse . words
```

I understand that because functional language like Haskell cannot be based on side effects of functions, some solution had to be invented. In this case it seems that everything has to be wrapped in a `do` block. I get simple examples, but in this case I really need someone's explanation:

1. Why isn't it enough to use one, single `do` block for I/O actions?
2. Why do you have to open completely new one in if/else case?
3. Also, when does the -- I don't know how to call it -- "scope" of the `do` monad ends, i.e. when can you just use standard Haskell terms/functions?

Comment: `do` is just syntactic sugar to avoid having to write overly complex statements with `>>=` and `>>` it works with all monads, and has no special association with IO. You don't have to use a second `do` in the example code(you don't even need the first `do` but the resulting code would be harder to read), you could also write `else putStrLn (reverseWords line) >> main` and it would have the same effect.

Comment: I've answered a largely similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049409/simple-haskell-code-cant-compile/23050814#23050814 Does that help? The trick is to basically look at the return types of all the functions, and everything will fall into place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488646/why-are-side-effects-modeled-as-monads-in-haskell?rq=1 has some more explanations.

Comment: [This](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) blog post is an excellent thing to read if you're struggling with monads in general, which seems to be the case. Read with a .hs file and ghci prompt open, so you can do the exercises.

Comment: Thank you a lot for help, good tutorial can explain everything much better to me than just theory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `do` block concerns anything *on the same indentation level as the first statement*. So in your example it's really just linking two things together:

```
 line <- getLine
```

and all the rest, which happens to be rather bigger:

```
 if null line  
  then return ()
  else do
      putStrLn $ reverseWords line  
      main
```

but no matter how complicated, the `do` syntax doesn't look *into* these expressions. So all this is exactly the same as

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   line <- getLine
   recurseMain line
```

with the helper function

```
recurseMain :: String -> IO ()
recurseMain line
   | null line  = return ()
   | otherwise  = do
           putStrLn $ reverseWords line
           main
```

Now, *obviously* the stuff in `recurseMain` can't know that the function is called within a `do` block from main, so you need to use another `do`.

Answer (score 8):

`do` doesn't actually do anything, it's just syntactic sugar for easily combining statements. A dubious analogy is to compare `do` to `[]`:

If you have multiple expressions you can combine them into lists using `:`:

```
(1 + 2) : (3 * 4) : (5 - 6) : ...
```

However, this is annoying, so we can instead use `[]` notation, which compiles to the same thing:

```
[1+2, 3*4, 5-6, ...]
```

Similarly, if you have multiple IO statments, you [can combine them using `>>` and `>>=`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation):

```
(putStrLn "What's your name?") >> getLine >>= (\name -> putStrLn $ "Hi " ++ name)
```

However, this is annoying, so we can instead use `do` notation, which compiles to the same thing:

```
do
  putStrLn "What's your name?"
  name <- getLine
  putStrLn $ "Hi " ++ name
```

Now the answer to why you need multiple `do` blocks is simple:

If you have multiple lists of values, you need multiple `[]`s (even if they're nested).

If you have multiple sequences of monadic statements, you need multiple `do`s (even if they're nested).